# Toggling div visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Would like to modify this toggle function so that the div content is retracted and hidden again when the same link is clicked again, as well as have it retract completely when a different link is clicked before the content associated with that link slides down.

Also would like to know how to change the link to a different color when its content is visible.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<script type="text/javascript"     
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function slideonlyonee(thechoseone) {
 $('.newframe').each(function(index) {
      if ($(this).attr("id") == thechoseone) {
           $(this).delay(400).slideDown(500);
      }
      else {
           $(this).slideUp(500);
      }
 });
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<!--COMEDY STARTS HERE-->
<div style="position:relative; top:2px; left:10px;"> 
<a id="myframe" style="text-decoration: none; "   
href="javascript:slideonlyonee('newframe2');"><span style="color:blue;">comedy</span>
</a>

<div class="newframe" id="newframe2" style="background: blue; display:none; block;   
padding: 5px; width: 450px; height:500px; position: relative; left:-5px; top:60px;">
</div>
</div>

<!--DRAMA STARTS HERE-->        
<div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:144px;"> 
<a id="myframe"  style="text-decoration: none;" 
href="javascript:slideonlyonee('newframe3');"><span style="color:red;">drama</span></a>

<div class="newframe" id="newframe3" style="background:  red; display:none; block;    
padding: 5px; width: 450px; height:500px; position: relative; left:-131px; top:60px;">
</div>
</div>

<!--CRIME STARTS HERE-->
<div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:283px;"> 
<a id="myframe" style="text-decoration: none;" 
href="javascript:slideonlyonee('newframe4');"><span style="color:green;">crime</a>

<div class="newframe" id="newframe4" style="background:  green; display:none; block; 
padding: 5px; width: 450px; height:500px; position: relative; left:-270px; top:60px;">
</div>
</div>

<!--MAKEOVER STARTS HERE-->
<div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:407px;"> 
<a id="myframe" style="text-decoration: none;" 
href="javascript:slideonlyonee('newframe5');"><span style="color:purple;">makeover</a>

<div class="newframe" id="newframe5" style="background:  purple; display:none; block;   
padding: 5px; width: 450px; height:500px; position: relative; left:-394px; top:60px;">
</div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

[**HERE'S THE WORKING CODE**](http://www.visuallypersuasive.com/jason/test_1.html)

Thanks in advance for any help, its much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(this).delay(400).slideToggle(500); //<---instead toggle the slide

$('[class="'+thechoseone+'"] span').css({'color':'orange', 'font-weight':'bold'});
//---------------------------^^^^---add this too.
```

You have same `id` for all links that's invalid use `class` instead.

So the finally html links should be:

```
<a class="myframe"
```

and jQuery:

```
function slideonlyonee(thechoseone) {
    $('.newframe').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).attr("class") == thechoseone) {
             $(this).delay(400).slideToggle(500);
             $('[class="'+thechoseone+'"] span').css({'color':'orange', 'font-weight':'bold'});
             //---------------------------^^^^---add this too.
         }
     });
 }
```

Comment: This is how I implemented your advice. 
    
    function slideonlyonee(thechoseone) {
     $('.newframe').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechoseone) {
              $(this).delay(400).slideToggle(500); //<---instead   
    toggle the slide
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(500);
          }
     });
    }

Comment: Oh just seen your markup closely you have same `id` for multiple links that is invalid.`ids should be unique to each elem` instead of `id` use `class`.

Comment: and just updated the answer `see the comments in the answer.`

Answer (score 1):

This may be the solution you are looking for:

```
function slideonlyonee( theLink,thechoseone ) {

   theLink.css('color','red');
    var theChosendDiv=$("#"+thechoseone);
    $(".newframe:not(#"+thechoseone+")").slideUp(500);

    theChosendDiv.delay(400).slideToggle(500);
}
```

The html should be:

```
<a id="myframe" style="text-decoration: none; "   
href="javascript:slideonlyonee(this,'newframe2');"><span style="color:blue;">comedy</span>
</a>
```